# Why can't we view deleted table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

What is meant by a "logical table?" i.e. `Deleted` and `Inserted`. That is, why can't we do something like:

```
Delete 
From exampletable

Select *
From deleted
```

In the same session and see the results from the deleted table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DELETED` and `INSERTED` tables are created by the SQL engine to handle the data manipulation in your data manipulation statement. Think of them as being similar to a temp table that you would create in a stored procedure to hold interim results.

Once your DML statement has completed, SQL Server doesn't need them anymore, so it "drops" the "temp tables" and they aren't there to query any longer. You can, though, access them using the `OUTPUT` clause in your DML statement, as @LucaszSzozda explains, because at that point, the engine hasn't dropped them yet.

Comment: Thank you @EricBrandt for clarifying. I thought that maybe it would exist for the duration of the transaction. After trying begin tran delete from testtable select * from deleted I see this is not the case. Thank you much.

Answer (score 2):

You probably search for `OUPUT` clause:

```
Delete From exampletable
OUTPUT deleted.*
```